# Data cannot find correctly by query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to develop a Mess Manager Application. Where users(members) comes and goes in every month.

Here is my Eloquent Query in my Controller which I tried:
where session('dates') like- Nov-2023, Dec-2023, Jan-2024

```php
$sessionDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('M-Y', session('dates'));
$currentDate = now();
$sessionDateNumeric = intval($sessionDate->format('Ym'));
$currentDateNumeric = intval($currentDate->format('Ym'));
if ($sessionDateNumeric == $currentDateNumeric) {
  $users = User::where('batch', $this->batch)->where('status', 'active')->get();
} elseif ($sessionDateNumeric < $currentDateNumeric) {
     $users = User::where('batch', $this->batch)
                ->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDate) {
                    $query->where('status', 'active')
                        ->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDate) {
                            $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $sessionDate->endOfMonth())
                                ->orWhereDate('updated_at', '<=', $sessionDate->endOfMonth());
                        });
                    $query->orWhere('status', 'inactive')
                        ->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDate) {
                            $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $sessionDate->endOfMonth())
                                ->orWhereDate('updated_at', '<=', $sessionDate->endOfMonth());
                    });
                })->get();
   } else {
  $users = [];
}
```

here is my user table in my MySQL database :

| Name | status | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M | active | 2023-12-09 16:33:08 | 2023-12-09 16:33:08 |
| N | active | 2023-10-11 16:52:49 | 2023-12-14 17:51:28 |
| L | inactive | 2023-11-15 18:02:36 | 2023-11-22 18:02:36 |
| K | active | 2023-11-08 04:20:23 | 2023-12-14 17:37:41 |
| S | active | 2023-12-14 05:27:27 | 2024-01-04 05:38:38 |

you can see in my data table- Oct-2023 month, 1 user is created, so October months $users=1person. Nov-2023 month, 2 users created and 1 user active from previous month so, total $users=3person. Dec-2023 month, 2 users created, 3 user active from previous month and which 1 user inactive in this month but i need his data, so total $users=4person and current month(Jan-2024) its enough to show all active users.

and my desired $users output for month Oct-2023= 1person(N), Nov-2023= 3person(N,L,K), Dec-2023=4person(M,N,K,S),Jan-2024=4person(M,N,K,S) details.   I hope I explain my problem.

Comment: What is the significance of using `>` for comparison? They are 2 strings.

Comment: oh, its my mistake, i was already edits my code. please check it one more time, and help me for finding solutions.

Comment: If you don't provide some time parts (days, hours, etc.), the current time will be used, e.g. Oct-2023 will be interpreted as 2023-10-05 xx:yy:zz. So the results of your conditions like `where('created_at', '<=', $sessionDate)` are dicey, you need to use a specific time point.

Comment: I don't need time period, I only need month value for comparing. if i use $sessionDate->endOfMonth(); then i find correct value, but one mistake in Dec-2023, give this all(5) users details, but there must have 4 user retained, 1 user inactive from previous month. I hope i catch my problem and explain properly.

Comment: Because `2023-11-22 18:02:36 < Dec-2023`, I think the right condition should be `updated_at >= 1-Dec-2023` or `updated_at >= $sessionDate->startOfMonth()`

Comment: $query->orWhere('status', 'inactive')
                        ->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDate) {
                            $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $sessionDate->endOfMonth())
                                ->orWhereDate('updated_at', '>=', $sessionDate->startOfMonth());
                        });  same output again

Comment: The relationship between two conditions should be `and`, not `or`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with this query

```
  $users = User::where('batch', $this->batch)
       ->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDate) {
        $query->where('status', 'active')
           ->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDate) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $sessionDate)
                ->orWhereDate('updated_at', '<=', $sessionDate);
        });

    $query->orWhere('status', 'inactive')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDate) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $sessionDate)
                ->orWhereDate('updated_at', '<=', $sessionDate);
        });
})
->get();
```

You can use this one

```
$users = User::where('batch', $this->batch)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDate) {
        $query->where('status', 'active')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDate) {
                $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $sessionDate->endOfMonth())
                    ->orWhereDate('updated_at', '<=', $sessionDate->endOfMonth());
            })
            ->orWhere('status', 'inactive')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDate) {
                $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $sessionDate->endOfMonth())
                    ->orWhereDate('updated_at', '<=', $sessionDate->endOfMonth());
            });
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: these query gives  almost correct answer when i added $sessionDate->endOfMonth(). but for month Dec-2023, there is an error again, give all(5) user.

Comment: I've update the code you can check the updated code.

Comment: I find my solutions that I posted as answer. Thanks a lot because you worked with my problems. Others give me only negative votes.

Answer (score 0):

I find my problems solutions-

```php
$sessionDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('M-Y', session('dates'));
        $currentDate = now();
        $currentDateNumeric = intval($currentDate->format('Ymd'));
        $sessionDateNumeric = intval($sessionDate->format('Ymd'));
        $sessionDateStartOfMonth = intval($sessionDate->startOfMonth()->format('Ymd'));
        $sessionDateEndOfMonth = intval($sessionDate->endOfMonth()->format('Ymd'));
        $sessionDateAddOneMonth = intval($sessionDate->startOfMonth()->addMonth()->format('Ymd'));
        $users = [];
        $users = User::when($sessionDateNumeric == $currentDateNumeric, function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'active');
        })
            ->when($sessionDateNumeric < $currentDateNumeric, function ($query) use ($sessionDateStartOfMonth, $sessionDateEndOfMonth, $sessionDateAddOneMonth) {
                $query->where(function ($query) use ($sessionDateAddOneMonth) {
                    $query->where('status', 'active')
                        ->where('created_at', '<=', $sessionDateAddOneMonth);
                })
                    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($sessionDateStartOfMonth, $sessionDateEndOfMonth) {
                        $query->where('status', 'inactive')
                            ->where('updated_at', '>=', $sessionDateStartOfMonth)
                            ->where('updated_at', '<=', $sessionDateEndOfMonth);
                    });
            })
            ->get();
```

Thanks for contributing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).